# Do keyboard autocomplete suggestions get transferred?

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct, dictionary

I used to have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and was using AT&T as my network provider. I lost my Nexus phone and bought and a new Samsung Nexus Mini.

When I installed Facebook and WhatsApp on my new phone, I can see all my keyboard suggestions, though the chat history from WhatsApp was deleted.

How did my phone remember (and transfer) all my keyboard autocomplete suggestions?

Comment: There's no such phone as a "Samsung Nexus Mini", but there are several with names of the form "Samsung something Mini". Please check what model of phone you have and [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: Are/were you using the default keyboard app, or did you install another such as SwiftKey? Word completions are provided by the keyboard app, not the app you're typing into.